# Glossary doesn't work, even though the Index, Acronym, abbreviation sections work.

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, books, makeindex

The list of Acronyms and Abbreviations appear at the end of the following document. The Index also appears at the end. So far so good ... until the Glossary which doesn't pop up.

I can't figure out why it remains invisible.

Any help would be welcome.
Thank you.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered]{book}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

% Creating Index
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\usepackage[toc,acronym,automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%%%%%TEST_ZONE%%%%%%

\newacronym{as}{A.S.}{All Salt}
\newacronym{oal}{OAL}{Omni Apple Legend}
\newacronym{ept}{EPT}{Emile Pot Trauma}

%%%%%TEST_ZONE%%%%%%

%Table of Content depth
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

%Hyperlinks for TOC
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\chapter{The Story}
\section{Data}

\gls{as} and \gls{oal} are terms used in the \gls{ept}.

Plants.\index{Plants}
Star.\index{star}
Mu.\index{Mu}
Sinis.\index{Sinis}
Ball.\index{Ball}

\chapter{Languages}
\section{Pronunciation}
\section{Scripts}

\backmatter

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Prove me wrong, but I see neither any entry added to the main glossary, neither is there any command to print the main glossary (`\printglossary[type=main]`).
_Further:_ Please reduce you example next time to the minimum of elements required, for instance we don't need all packages for the example.

Comment: Sorry about the length, again. I kept all the packages in in case there was conflicts between them. As for the rest: doesn't this suffice: \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations] to at least have the glossary section appear at the end of the document?

Comment: Even when I add an entry like this (\newglossaryentry{Water}
{name=water, description={is a liquid.}}) in the preamble, the glossary doesn't pop up.

Comment: This command will only print the Abbreviations section, nothing else. I'm not sure right now if an empty glossary would be printed at all, but you should get the title if you add the command I stated above.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I added \printglossary[type=main] right after \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations] at the bottom of the document, along with the following \newglossaryentry{Water} {name=water, description={is a liquid.}} entry in the preamble. Nothing.

Comment: Have you checked the transcript for messages or warnings? (The document `.log` file and the `makeindex` log file, which has the extension `.alg` for the `acronym` type.) Since you've used the `automake` option, also check that the shell escape is enabled. (Search for `runsystem` in the `.log` file.)

Comment: I tried to run the example now myself, and it failed. However, I did get it to work with the following changes:
Add the package option `xindy` to change the tool that creates the glossaries. Add a glossary entry and the print command as above. And - at any point in the document - add `\glsaddall`. Now you should have a glossary.

Comment: The issue is fixed: I installed Perl (which I realized I needed after I looked at the log, per Nicola's suggestion), and I changed the code per Timm's comments. Duh. Thank you for the help. StackExchange is the best.